# Can SharePoint Online view External Office Documnets?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rendering

The Microsoft Office Viewer does what I need it to do, except that the documents are coped to an external server to be rendered in the browser, which is not acceptable at my company.  The URL looks like this:

```
http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://someUrl/someDocument.docx
```

SharePoint Online can view and edit documents that exist on our SharePoint site.  The URL contains the GUID of the document and looks like this:

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/siteName/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B12345678-1234-ABCD-5678-1234567890AB%7D
```

Is there a way to construct a SharePoint Online URL that will display external Office Documents?  You would think it should be as simple as this:

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/.../Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=http://someUrl/someDocument.docx
```

SharePoint Online clearly has the capability to view Office Documents in the browser, and I'm already paying for that feature, so how can I leverage that functionality to view external documents?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, SharePoint online only could share files stored in the existing SharePoint sites.